# Declaring Dates and Nulls in function calls

Tags: function, parameter-passing, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When I call a function eg

```
SELECT  * FROM TABLE(FN_ABC(NULL::DATE , '2022-04-07'::DATE ))
```

Snowflake forces me to bind the parameters Im passing to a datatype eg DATE and for all NULLs as above.

Is there a way to avoid binding them? I've already declared them as DATES in my function

ie simply just call it without the datatypes

```
SELECT  * FROM TABLE(FN_ABC(NULL, '2022-04-07'))
```

the reason is these parameters are being passed from a webpage as just NULL or 2022-04-07

Thank you

Comment: Date should not be an issue, given function signature include type as DATE. The issue is with NULLs. Possibly something to follow up with support or if its as per design and needs to be handled in application. In case a function is defined without any arguments and its called with NULL keyword, then it throws error. Same is case with if we pass NULL in function call against any function defined with any datatype as argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your sql is not two dates, it's an undefined type, and a string/text/varchar.

```
select
    null as a
    ,'2022-04-07' as b
    ,system$typeof(a) as t_a
    ,system$typeof(b) as t_b
    ,a::date as d_a
    ,b::date as d_b
    ,system$typeof(d_a) as t_da
    ,system$typeof(d_b) as t_db
```

| A | B | T_A | T_B | D_A | D_B | T_DA | T_DB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| null | 2022-04-07 | NULL[LOB] | VARCHAR(10)[LOB] | null | 2022-04-07 | DATE[SB4] | DATE[SB4] |

Thus using those values gives you an error:

> 001044 (42P13): SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 21
>
> Invalid argument types for function 'FN_ABC': (NULL, VARCHAR(10))

But if you already have `DATE` values, there is not problem:

```
with data as (
  select 
    null as a
    ,'2022-04-07' as b
    ,system$typeof(a) as t_a
    ,system$typeof(b) as t_b
    ,a::date as d_a
    ,b::date as d_b
     ,system$typeof(d_a) as t_da
    ,system$typeof(d_b) as t_db
  )
SELECT 
    f.*
FROM data as d
,table(fn_abc(d.d_a, d.d_b)) f;
```

runs, just fine

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| null | 2022-04-07 |

Comment: Thanks Simeon I've fixed my code and dates work now. Im still having errors with NULLs being passed in the function from a web page.

Invalid argument types for function 'PRS.FN_ABC': (VARCHAR(27), NULL)) I have to add 
PRS.FN_ABC': (VARCHAR(27), NULL::VARCHAR))

Comment: @Leon I am not sure if that is a statement or a question.